# Writing a results to a .txt file using csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I need the results of this script ie, pygoogle search results, to go like so:

```
name    # of results
name    # of results
name    # of results
```

Here is what I have so far, how can I do this without re writing the file each time:

```
import re
import pygoogle
import csv
from pygoogle import pygoogle
#creates list
with open('parse2.txt') as f:
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f.read().strip('\'"[]').split(' '*6)]
#googles each name in list
for line in lines:
    g = pygoogle(line)
    g.pages = 1
    names = [line + "    " + "%s results" %(g.get_result_count())]
    if (g.get_result_count()) == 0:
        print "ERROR. SEARCH NOT SUCCSESSFUL. TRY AGAIN IN A FEW MINUTES."
    elif (g.get_result_count()) > 0:
    print names
    for name in names:
        with open("output.txt", "wb+") as f:
            f.writelines(name)
```

When I run the script, the output only shows the most recent one, for it is re-writing the script:

Comment: `A` is not a list, it is a string. You'll probably want to split it first. What is `names`?

Comment: You are also clearing and rewriting 'output.csv' every time the `for name` loop executes.

Comment: Why are you acutually using `csv.writer`? Wouldn't it be easier to write the file on your own? Something like `','.join(your_list)`?

Comment: Is A really a string of comma separated values?  Adding the brackets does make it a list, but it's now a list of len==1...  Is it actually a list `A = ['blah blah', 'blah blah', 'blah list']`, or a string?

Comment: WAT? What's with changing the question completely?

Comment: @brice No one seemed to understand, what I was talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overcoming confusion on looping behaviour:

The `names` variable will be a list with only one item in it every time you use it. Do this instead:

```
import re
import csv
from pygoogle import pygoogle

names = []

with open('parse2.txt') as fin:
   names = [x.strip() for x in fin.read().strip('\'"[]').split(' '*6)]

with open("output.txt") as fout:
  for name in names:
    g = pygoogle(name)
    g.pages = 1
    if (g.get_result_count()) == 0:
      print "[Error]: could find no result for '{}'".format(name)
    else:
      fout.write("{}    {} results\n".format(name, g.get_result_count()) )
```

### Writing out the file once

*Without overwriting previous queries*

You need to invert the order of the `with` and `for` statements, which will open the file once:

```
with open("output.txt", "wb+") as f:
  for line in lines:
    # Stuff...
    for name in names:
      f.writelines(name)
```

Or, open the file in append mode:

```
for name in names:
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
        f.writelines(name)
```

In which case the data will be added at the end.

### Transforming the data

The steps to take to get what you want.

1. Transform your original list into a list of words.
2. Group the list into pairs.
3. Write out the pairs.

As follows:

```
import re
from itertools import *

A = ["blah blah", "blah blah", "blah", "list"]

#
# from itertools doc page
#
def flatten(listOfLists):
  "Flatten one level of nesting"
  return list(chain.from_iterable(listOfLists))

def pairwise(t):
  it = iter(t)
  return izip(it,it)

#
# Transform data
#
list_of_lists = [re.split("[ ,]", item) for item in A]
# [['blah', 'blah'], ['blah', 'blah'], ['blah'], ['list']]
a_words = flatten(list_of_lists)
a_pairs = pairwise(a_words)

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a_pairs)
```

Which is more succinctly written as:

```
A_pairs = pairwise(flatten([re.split("[ ,]", item) for item in A]))
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(A_pairs)
```

### Writing out in the right format

If you don't want commas in the output, simply define a custom dialect for your `csvwriter`:

```
>>> csv.register_dialect('mydialect', delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> csv.writer(open("try.csv", "w"), dialect="mydialect").writerows(a_ps)
```

which gives what you want:

```
➤ cat try.csv 
blah blah
blah blah
blah list
```

Comment: this worked in adding the file, but is there a way to make it like the way I described it, with each name and # of results in one line?

Answer (score 0):

To write appending to the file, without rewriting, add `+` to the mode:

```
for name in names:
    with open("output.txt", "wb+") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(A)
```

On the other hand, for better efficiency, you can open the file only once and use the file methods instead the CSV module:

```
with open("output.txt", "wb+") as f:
    f.writelines(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> A = ["blah blah", "blah blah", "blah", "list"]
>>> lis = [y for x in A for y in x.split()]
>>> lis
['blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'list']
>>> it = iter(lis)
>>> with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
         writer.writerows([ [x,next(it)] for x in it])
```